# Conversion array types

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have in table column, which type is `CHARACTER VARYING[]` (that is array)

I need concatenate existed rows whith other array

This is my code:

```
UPDATE my_table SET
col = array_cat(col, ARRAY['5','6','7'])
```

returned error:  `function array_cat(character varying[], text[]) does not exist`

Reason error is that array types not matches right?

Question: how to convert this array `ARRAY['5','6','7']` as `CHARACTER VARYING[]` type ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Cast to `varchar[]`:

```
 > SELECT ARRAY['5','6','7']::varchar[], pg_typeof( ARRAY['5','6','7']::varchar[] );

 SELECT ARRAY['5','6','7']::varchar[], pg_typeof( ARRAY['5','6','7']::varchar[] );
  array  |      pg_typeof      
---------+---------------------
 {5,6,7} | character varying[]
```

You can use the PostgreSQL specific `::varchar[]` or the standard `CAST(colname AS varchar[])`... though as arrays are not consistent across database implementations there won't be much advantage to using the standard syntax.